# SQLAlchemy problem with relationship many to many

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a issue using SQLAlchemy.

```
Base = declarative_base()

node_to_node = Table("node_to_node", Base.metadata,
    Column("left_node_id", Integer, ForeignKey("node.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("right_node_id", Integer, ForeignKey("node.id"), primary_key=True)
)

class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String)
    right_nodes = relationship("Node",
                        secondary=node_to_node,
                        primaryjoin=id==node_to_node.c.left_node_id,
                        secondaryjoin=id==node_to_node.c.right_node_id,
                        backref="left_nodes"
    )

metadata = Base.metadata

engine = create_engine("postgres+psycopg2://postgres:admin@localhost:5432/test")
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)

s = session()

node1 = Node(label="node1")
node2 = Node(label="node2")
node3 = Node(label="node3")
node1.right_nodes.append(node2)
node1.right_nodes.append(node3)
s.add_all([node1, node2, node3])
s.commit()
```

what I want is to have the IDs of all the right nodes of node 1 as an array, so here [2, 3]
Do you know a method that allows me to do that?

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT :

```
class NeedTag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'need_tags'
    tag_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id'), primary_key=True)
    text_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('texts.id'), primary_key=True)

class Text(Base) : 
    __tablename__ = 'texts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(Text, nullable=False)

    need_tag = relationship("Tag", 
                            secondary="need_tags")

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(), nullable=False)
```

I have a problem with the SQL Alchemy synthax.
For example, I defined the Text and Tags class and a many-to-many relationship between Text and Tags: To use a text, you need to have some tags that must be present.

An example of a condition is: 
If tag1 or tag2 : 
     If tag3 or tag 4 : 
           Text1 can be used

I would like to do this:

```
text1.need_tags = [ [tag1, tag2],[tag3, tag4] ]
```

And therefore to use text1, you need at least 1 tag in the 1st list AND 1 tag in the 2nd list

But I tried so many techniques and they all failed

Do you know if it is possible to do that with SQLAlchemy ? Or something like that that accomplish the same thing

Comment: `[node.id for node in node1.right_nodes]`?

Comment: I was also wondering: is it possible to add at the same time node2 and node3 to node1's right nodes in one line of code ? Instead of using node1.right_nodes.append(node2), node1.right_nodes.append(node3), is there any method which acts like node1.right_nodes.append([node2, node3]) (this one does not work) ?

Comment: Relationship attributes are just lists by default. So if you are just initially setting the relationship `node1.right_nodes = [node2, node3]`. If you want to add to an existing relationship collection, `node1.right_nodes += [node2, node3]`.

Comment: Hi @AlbertTho, you should really ask a new question rather than edit an old question to include a new problem.